# Cannot filter dates at pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file which contains multiple columns and one of them is called `Date` and has date values of 2018 like that:

[image]

The format is `Date` at the .csv for this column.

I am going the following at my source code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data
data_daily = pd.read_csv('Desktop/data_daily.csv', keep_default_na=True)

# Filter data_daily down to only October
data_daily = data_daily[(data_daily['Date'] > '01/10/2018') & (data_daily['Date'] < '31/10/2018')]

# Save as a new .csv file
data_daily.to_csv('Desktop/final.csv', index=False)
```

However, the final .csv file has all the dates and not only the ones which I want.

I do not know if this makes a difference but keep in mind that there are multiple lines which have the same date.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "The format is Date at the .csv for this column." means the dtype is datetime?

Comment: No it is object

Comment: convert `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

Comment: I had done this: `data_daily['Date'] = pd.datetime(data_daily['Date'])`  and then I am getting this error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for parse column to datetimes:

```
data_daily = pd.read_csv('Desktop/data_daily.csv',
                         keep_default_na=True, 
                         parse_dates=['Date'],
                         dayfirst=True)
```

And then use your solution or alternative with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with converting strings to `Timestamp`:

```
s = pd.Timestamp('2018-10-01')
e = pd.Timestamp('2018-10-31')
data_daily = data_daily[data_daily['Date'].between(s, e, inclusive=False)]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187695/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-cannot-filter-dates-at-pandas-dataframe).